# react-native use Image Component crash,excepiton NSRangeException

Tags: image, react-native

```js
2016-01-06 20:07:21.905 AwsomeProject_17[871:54535] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFString substringFromIndex:]: Index 187 out of bounds; string length 186'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010936ee65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108572deb objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010936ed9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
 3   Foundation                          0x000000010811a11d -[NSString substringFromIndex:] + 126
 4   AwsomeProject_17                    0x0000000107ea4205 RCTBundlePathForURL + 293
 5   AwsomeProject_17                    0x0000000107ea428d RCTIsXCAssetURL + 45
 6   AwsomeProject_17                    0x0000000107ef62e0 -[RCTXCAssetImageLoader canLoadImageURL:] + 48
 7   AwsomeProject_17                    0x0000000107eed887 -[RCTImageLoader imageURLLoaderForURL:] + 615
 8   AwsomeProject_17                    0x0000000107eeec80 __87-[RCTImageLoader loadImageWithTag:size:scale:resizeMode:progressBlock:completionBlock:]_block_invoke_2125 + 368
 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8f1e5d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c91249b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8f88ec _dispatch_queue_drain + 2215
 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8f7e0d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 601
 13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8faa56 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1420
 14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010c8fa4c5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
 15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010cc4a68f _pthread_wqthread + 1129
 16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010cc48365 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I wrote a ListView Component which every row contain a image,The Image use uri to fetch the source,but when I fetch the wrong image sources ,the whole app crashing! It's very odd,because I use 'abcdeee' to replace the item.image.it still work ,there is no crash.
and My code is

```js
renderMovie(item) {
        console.log(item.image);
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.toContent(item.id)}}>
                <View style={styles.Items}>
                    <Image
                        source={{uri:item.image}}
                        style={styles.thumbnail}
                    />
                    <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.mtitle}>{item.byzd1}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Show your code! Please edit your question!

Comment: @jogo It's my first time to post a question here,

Comment: Can you check if `item.image` is null?

Comment: The image source url is  determined by the user,So I can't avoid this happened.